# Is it possible to share files through Apache WebDAV?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, webdav, owncloud, nextcloud

Apache WebDAV allows to setup a WebDAV server without the PHP overhead which is usualy produced through Nextcloud/Owncloud. But is it also able to:

- share a file / folder with other authed users?
- share a file / folder by link for a guest?

Does Apache WebDAV include a WebGUI which has such a feature or how does it work?

Comment: You might want to clarify exactly what you want to achieve, as it's possible there are simpler, more modern tools to get the same outcome

Answer (score 1):

### Note:

personally I think of webdav as being an obsolete protocol, and generally there are newer, easier tools for sharing files securely. I like [syncthing](https://syncthing.net/)

### That said:

You could combine the webdav module with [apache's Authentication and Authorization modules](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html) to achieve user and group level access to specific webdav directories as described in this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-webdav-access-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

(You would probably also want to [setup TLS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04) to secure your site before exposing this to the public internet)

Apache config would look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ...

    Alias /webdav /var/www/webdav

    <Directory "/var/www/webdav">
        DAV On

        AuthType Digest
        AuthName "Restricted Files"
        AuthUserFile "/usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords"
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>
```

and you can add users to the webdav password file using something like

```
sudo htdigest -c /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords webdav userxxx
```

and they would be required to provide a valid user/password when accessing the webdav share.

With regard to your question about a webdav GUI. I don't think that apache provides anything to manage users, access and directives outside configuration files. However there are some tools like webmin that offer some sort of web interface to apache configuration - https://webmin.com/apache.html - which might be enough.

Additionally, it's possible to use alternative backends for user authentication, such as LDAP - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html , which is a good option if you already have ldap from Active Directory, or some other Single sign on platform in place.

Once you had configured LDAP, you could then use any standard LDAP management tool to administrate users, groups and passwords for access to the webdav, such as JXexplorer - http://jxplorer.org/

Comment: I didn't asked for a Gui to add users. I asked for sharing files. That's the reason why syncthing is not an alternative to WebDav, it's only an alternative sync protocol: https://forum.syncthing.net/t/how-do-you-share-your-files/2515 I highlighted the sharing part in my question.